# Strange gulp-sass issues compiling extra files

Tags: javascript, node.js, gulp, build-process, gulp-sass

I am new to using **gulp** and **npm packages** so this maybe *normal behaviour*.

My issue is that I am setting up a new project and have all the packages I need including Browserify when I run `gulp` in terminal the files all compile perfectly and minify as expected although there is a small niggling issues I see which is that my sass files in the pre compile folder seem to compile into `.css.map` and `.css` when I make changes to the css. This  is an extra process and creates extra files which I do not like.

Is this normal behaviour?

My tasks is as follows and I have tested it to know its to do with gulp sass:

```
var src = {
    sass: "src/sass/**/*.scss",
    js: "src/js/**/*.js",
    img: "src/img/*"
};

var output = {
    js: "output/js",
    css: "output/css",
    img: "output/img/",
    html: "output/**/*.html",
    min_css: "app.min.css",
    min_js: "app.min.js"
};

gulp.task('sass', function() {

    return gulp.src(src.sass)
        .pipe(plumber({
            errorHandler: onError
        }))
        .pipe(sass())
        .pipe(prefix('last 2 versions'))
        .pipe(concat(output.min_css))
        .pipe(gulp.dest(output.css))
        .pipe(minify_css())
        .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
        .pipe(sourcemaps.write())
        .pipe(gulp.dest(output.css))
        .pipe(browseSync.reload({stream: true}));

});
```

For more information I have node v5.6.0 and gulp CLI version 1.2.1
gulp Local version 3.9.1.

Maybe there is a weird thing to do with versions of my dev tools?

Any information would be great thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you're generating [sourcemaps](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-sourcemaps). Check out what you are calling...

```
.pipe(sourcemaps.init())
.pipe(sourcemaps.write())
```

So yes, this is normal since you are explicitly calling it. Just delete these `pipe` calls to not write sourcemap files.

Comment: Great that did solve it i was following a tutorial and they were using it for some reason. Thanks!